# Can I use a Directive in the template function?

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

So this is a simple example i just wrote up for the sake of this question, I'm curious if I'm able to use a directive and pass in an object to the directive's attribute, all in the template, **not templateUrl**. I would think it would work something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        u: '=',
      },
      template: '<avatar user="u"></avatar>',
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! And it doesn't matter the definition order.

```
app.directive("directive1", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            u: '@'
        },
        template : "<h4>{{u}}</h4><directive2 user='{{u}}'></directive2>"
    };
});
app.directive("directive2", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            user: '@'
        },
        template : "<h1>{{user}}</h1>"
    };
});
```

See it in action in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phxyh794/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you expand the example to have an attribute passed in? Preferably an object

Comment: Sure! See it now.

Comment: I used a string just to make it easy to test and see the result. If you want to use an object change `@` with `=` and change what do you print (`u.name` for example)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's easy to pass your state through scope attributes. Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IXkgVfmHJBdBr6pgm4Dq?p=preview) that demonstrates the concept.

```
app = angular.module('app',[])
  .directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        u: '=',
      },
      template: '<avatar user="u"></avatar>',
    };
  }).directive('avatar', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        user: '=',
      },
      template: '<span>{{user.name}}</span>',
    };
  })
```